# Can we skip the parameter in event function?

Tags: javascript

Cuz if I skip it, the output is the same. Why we need it?

```
<p id='p'>TEXT</p>
   <script>
       p.onclick=function(event){        //with parameter
           alert(event.target.tagName);  //P
       }
   </script>
```

Now skip `event`, same output.

```
<p id='p'>TEXT</p>
       <script>
           p.onclick=function(){        //without parameter
               alert(event.target.tagName);  //P
           }
       </script>
```

Many tutorial will keep the parameter, I wonder why we need it? Why don't we make it simple? I just keep the original name of `event` in the function and it works out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`window.event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) is deprecated and is not supported by all browsers.

> You should avoid using this property in new code, and should instead use the Event passed into the event handler function. This property is not universally supported and even when supported introduces potential fragility to your code.